# im trying to useState and put in it multiple values from user input

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use state and put in it multiple values from user input but when l insert new values the rest of the useState object turns to undefined
[first textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S10Oo.png)

[all text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCCQx.png)

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdcbb.jpg)
[input code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLc4p.jpg)

l don't understand why does it turn to undefined after moving and typing in another input text box and when l send it to the API to save it in the database some values register as undefined

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXJt9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... Each state update for the `useState` hook is a *complete replacement* of the existing state.  So each time you call `setBook` you have to provide it with a complete object.  If the object you provide it with has only one property, then the new state now has only one property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because

```
(e) => setBook({name: e.target.value})
```

overwrites the current value.
You can instead do

```
(e) => setBook((book) => ({...book, name: e.target.value}))
```

to merge everything from the existing object and the new name.